# Is there any way to allow .write permission only for specific package name in Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an client app, And admin app through which I updates the client app (with different package name). How can I set rules for Firebase real-time database to allow only .write permission for my admin app (package name based). I don't implement login functionality for admin app.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing isn't possible to do securely.  You can't use anything about the app itself as a way to limit access in security rules.  That's just not very secure, as the end user has full control over their device, and the Realtime Database APIs are fully available to the public via a REST API.

You will need to make users sign in with Firebase Auth, give them some sort of specific admin access, perhaps through [custom claims](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims) that you grant on your backend, and use that to allow access to the data they need to read and write.